# Drop an empty column of the dataframe does not work

Tags: python, dataframe

My question has been asked multiple times and I implemented the provided answers but none of them worked. I have a [dataframe](http://www.filedropper.com/mydata_4) which contains an object column where all of its cells are empty strings. I have been trying to drop it through using the following methods separately each time:

```
data.dropna()
data.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)
data.dropna(axis='columns', how='all', inplace=True)
data.mask(data.astype(bool)).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
data.dropna(subset=['columnName'], inplace=True) 

filter = data['columnName'] != ""
data = data[filter]
```

Also, once I tried to replace the empty cells with `Nan` by using:

```
data['columnName'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

and then drop the column but strangely nothing was even changed to `NaN` in the corresponding column. In the above lines of code whereever it was required I assigned the result of the methods to `data` again but non of them worked. I wonder what to use instead that works?

This is a sample data:

```
BUILDING CATEGORY      MEANS OF ACCESS      ADDRESS      PRICE
rental                                        UK       £700000
commercial                                    UK       £5000000
```

I intend to drop MEANS OF ACCESS.

**UPDATE**
The code snippet is as follows:

```
# Remove the initial 2 rows
data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=2, low_memory=False)

# Remove the irrelevant columns
data = data.drop(['REGION', 'NUMBER'], axis=1)

# Remove '$' sign
data['PRICE'] = [x[1:] for x in data['PRICE']]

columns = ['WHOLE UNITS', 'AREA', 'PRICE']

# Remove comma
data[columns] = data[columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ''))

# Convert to numeric
data[columns] = data[columns].apply(pd.to_numeric)

# Remove duplicate rows
data.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

print((data['MEANS OF ACCESS'] == "").sum())  #returns 0 but it shouldn't
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. _I have a dataframe which contains an object column where all of its cells are empty._ They can't truly be "empty", I think, are they empty strings?

Comment: @AMC Yes, they are empty strings.

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: That data is not in a very convenient format, nor is it necessary easy to reproduce accurately. We're still missing an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the column `'column_name'`, then simply use

```py
df = df.drop(labels=['column_name'], axis=1)
```

If you want to drop all columns which contain only empty strings, then use

```py
df = df.replace('', pd.NA).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The first method works but the second one doesn't and actually as I mentioned in my question as well, it does not even change the empty strings to NaN. But what I am going to do is by using a loop over all columns firstly check if they contain just empty strings and if so then use the first method you provided for that column.

Comment: Even more strangly `data['columnName']=='').sum()` returns 0 although the column has just empty strings. Also, I converted the column to string by `data['columnName'].astype(str)` and then used `data['columnName']=='').sum()` but again the result was 0.

Comment: _The first method works but the second one doesn't and actually as I mentioned in my question as well, it does not even change the empty strings to NaN._ I know, but it should, and there's nothing I can do without an accurate representation of your data and program.

Comment: Shall I share the results of head() in my question or more than that?

Comment: @Bsh The problem with `head()` is that it formats the data for printing, but you lose precious information like the dtypes. The ideal would be to find a snippet of code which can consistently reproduce and demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I have added the snippet, please have a look, thanks.

Comment: @Bsh That requires the CSV file, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208327/discussion-between-bsh-and-amc).